# When representing 2^n x 2^n matrices using quadtrees

Tags: haskell, matrix, quadtree

I've just found the definition on my textbook and can't imagine what `nexp` is supposed to do/mean:

```
data (Eq a, Show a) => QT a = C a | Q (QT a) (QT a) (QT a) (QT a)
    deriving (Eq, Show)

data (Eq a, Num a, Show a) => Mat a = Mat {
    nexp :: Int,
    mat :: QT a}
    deriving (Eq,Show)
```

**What is the purpose of `nexp :: Int`**?

Comment: What does the textbook use it for?

Comment: @Jeremiah Willcock: It's mainly an exercise one, so it really never use it, I should :). Btw, when calculating if the matrix is lower triangular, it says: "pay attention at what the function should return, say, for `$ Mat 0 (C 2)` and `$ Mat 1 (C 2)`". Nothing more... the rest is just a list of exercises.

Comment: What textbook is this from? If you're currently taking a class that uses this textbook, I'd suggest you ask your professor. If not, then I'd suggest you find a professor that teaches with this book and ask him.

Comment: @Dan: apart from asking him or not, there MUST be a reason for using it :) and I'd like to find out asap... that's because I'm asking it.

Comment: @Robert Massaioli: it's one written by my professor... why? :p

Comment: Because I would not mind reading through a book that speaks about functional programming and Quadtrees in the same sentence. So does this book have a name or did your professor just write it for the class?

Comment: @Robert Massaioli: interesting, you should just explain a bit more the thing "FP and quadtrees". The book is written by my professor just for this class...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My best guess is that `nexp` is just the *n* used in the *exp*-onent to define how large the matrix is (`2^n x 2^n`).

Comment: Could be ^_^, that's why he's saying: pay attention to `Mat 0 (C 2)` and `Mat 1 (C 2)` when you check for lowertriangular": of course 1 x 1 matrix (with number 2 inside) is lower triangular, while 2 x 2 matrix (full of 2) is not.